# Is it possible to connect a transistor in common emitter configuration without using two supply voltages?

Tags: transistors

This is a theoretical question which occurred to me after my electronics teacher told me that common emitter requires two separate voltages. However when I asked her she told me that it was hypothetically possible to connect it with just one voltage. On searching the net I've found only dual voltage supply circuits for CE config , so i just wondered if there was anyone who had used only one supply source, and if so, then how exactly does that circuit work?

Comment: Supplies or references?

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by reference? The two voltages I referred to were connected between base  and emitter and collector and emitter. I wanted to know if it was possible to make do without one of them

Comment: @user235315 he means we need to see the circuit you are talking about. Common Emitter usually needs one power supply and an input voltage (the signal you are trying to amplify).

Comment: I don't know what you've seen, but common emitter amplifiers usually use just a single supply.  DC biasing needs to be considered, of course, but the DC operating point voltages and currents are usually derived from the same supply that provides the amplifier power.  The hard part would be finding a real world circuit that uses two supplies for a single common emitter stage.  Your teacher needs to get out more into the world of real circuit design.

Comment: I was  talking about circuits in general and not any circuit in particular. Strangely though I only saw circuits that had dual voltage supplies( i 'm sorry I did not mention it but i needed this only for DC sources and not AC sourced circuits)

Comment: @user235315 - a common emitter for dc signals is significantly better served by an op-amp. After all, how would you distinguish between the required transistor bias voltages (base and collector) and the signal?

Comment: Okay, i did not know about this stuff about an op amp,not having worked with them. Thanks a lot guys. will pass this on to my teacher.

Answer (score 1):

1st hit on google (common emitter amplifier): -

[image]

2nd hit on google: -

[image]

3rd hit on google: -

[image]

Need I say anymore?